# Cannot Cause Custom AuthorizeAttribute to be Called

Tags: authorize-attribute

The authentication works. All good there, not worried about that, I get a 401 if I don't send a proper token.

What I want to do is control REST API methods by user. So I am given to understand the way to do that is to put an attribute on the method that is derived from AuthorizeAttribute.

I am trying to achieve a dirt-simple way of denying access to the MakeComplexNote method.

The problem is that the code in the attribute is never called. Ever. Except the constructor.

I'm not concerned about the *merits* of what I am trying to do. I just want to know the *mechanics*. I am tired of fighting with this. How do I do it with the least amount of code possible?

Here is my controller:

```
using FleetApi.AuthProvider;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace FleetApi.Controllers
{
    public class MakeSimpleNoteRequest
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class MakeSimpleNoteResponse
    {
        public string FinalNote { get; set; }
    }



    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/notes")]
    public class NotesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route(nameof(MakeSimpleNote))]
        public MakeSimpleNoteResponse MakeSimpleNote([FromBody] MakeSimpleNoteRequest request)
        {
            return new MakeSimpleNoteResponse()
            {
                FinalNote = request?.Content?.ToUpper(),
            };
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route(nameof(MakeComplexNote))]
        [FleetAuthorize]
        public MakeSimpleNoteResponse MakeComplexNote([FromBody] MakeSimpleNoteRequest request)
        {
            return new MakeSimpleNoteResponse()
            {
                FinalNote = "COMPLEX:" + (request?.Content?.ToUpper()),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the custom attribute

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FleetApi.AuthProvider
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class FleetAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public FleetAuthorizeAttribute()
        {
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the answer. I needed to use

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

instead of

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

to get the base class for my attribute

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace FleetApi.AuthProvider
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class FleetAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public FleetAuthorizeAttribute()
        {
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            return false;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent("{}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The null ```{}``` JSON response isn't necessary ... in fact I don't think ```HandleUnauthorizedRequest``` even has to be there